# Python: How does one print bitshifted inputs as an integer?

Tags: python, bit-shift

I am trying to create a bitshifting tutorial script that takes a users input and prints the result, but it keeps returning the below error

```js
DATASET NUMBER: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 21, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'int'
```

**Here is my code I am currenly using:**

```js
import sys

input = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    input.append(line)
a = input[0]
b = input[1]
c = input[2]

a >> 4
print(a)

b << 2
print(b)

c << 1
print(c)
```

It is the printing part that is not working properly. I believe it is either a syntax error or an error with integer conversion, which I am not 100% confident in doing. Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something simple?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to apply the bit shift operator to a string, which doesn't make any sense. You would need to convert the string to an integer first. You're also not doing anything with the *result* of the shift operation.

Comment: As much as I understand, what you are taking as user input is a string and you cannot apply bitshift to a string. Maybe, you can convert to integer, `int(line)`. Note that it should be guaranteed that the input can be converted to integer.

Comment: (1) you need to convert your inputs to an integer, (2) you need to re-assign the shifted value back to the variable: `a = a >> 4` or more concisely: `a >>= 4`.

Comment: @Larsks yes, do you know how I would fix this in order to make it functional? (The result is not important atm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    input.append(line)
```

So `input` contains variables of type `str`, right? You can't byteshift a `str`ing, you have to cast it to an integer first:

```
input = list(map(int, input)) # This converts all the elements to integers
```

I would suggest an ending underscore to prevent your program from overwriting the built-in function `input`.

---

You should also be aware that you're not assigning the shifted value back to the variable, so you are `print`ing the same value found in the input.

```
a = a >> 4 # Do this...
a >>= 4 # ...maybe this...
a >> 4 # ...but for sure not this
```

Comment: Don't forget that OP doesn't actually assign the shifted value back to the variable.